# WPF AutoCompleteBox Popup Background

Tags: wpf, popup, autocompletebox

I have several AutoCompleteBox's in my usercontrol.  The box's that are individual display the results with a white background which I would assume is the default.  For whatever reason when I have an AutoCompleteBox within my ListBox.ItemContainerStyle the background on the popup is grey.  Any idea why it would be different?

Here is example code on one that is white:

```
    <controls:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Row="6" x:Name="FacilityCompleteBox" TextChanged="FacilityCompleteBox_OnTextChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ValueMemberPath="ListName" SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=patientVisitControl, Path=ClaimViewModel.SelectedFacility, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  LostFocus="CompleteBox_OnLostFocus" Text="{Binding ElementName=patientVisitControl, Path=ClaimViewModel.Visit.Facility.Facility.ListName}">
           <controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ListName}" />
              </DataTemplate>
           </controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:AutoCompleteBox>
```

And here is my Listbox which has a grey background on the popup:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="Resources" Grid.Row="8" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClaimViewModel.Claim.PatientVisitResources}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="White">
           <ListBox.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                 <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                          <ItemsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                       </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
              </Style>
           </ListBox.Resources>
           <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
              <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                 <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                          <!--<claimOverlay:PopupFilterControl x:Name="ResourceSearchFilter" SearchControlViewModel="{Binding}" ClaimOverlayWindow="{Binding ElementName=patientVisitControl, Path=ClaimOverlayWindow}" Height="30" MaxHeight="30" 
                                                           DeleteResource="ResourceSearchFilter_OnDeleteResource" SelectCard="Default_OnSelectCard" />-->
                          <controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="ResourceCompleteBox" TextChanged="ResourceCompleteBox_OnTextChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ValueMemberPath="ListName" 
                                                    LostFocus="CompleteBox_OnLostFocus" Text="{Binding Path=ListName}">
                             <controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ListName}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                             </controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                          </controls:AutoCompleteBox>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
              </Style>
           </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

There aren't any other styles for ListBox within my user control.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume there is a style somewhere in the ListBox that is making it turn grey so using the AutoCompleteBoxes ItemContainerStyle property I created the following style:

```
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
     <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
```

This style now changes my listbox popup background back to white to match the other AutoCompleteBoxes in my control.